# Bing API parameter having invalid value

Tags: php, bing-api

I am trying to use Bing API for my application. So far I am using sample codes available in different websites. But everytime I am getting a same error.

I am not understading the meaning of error. I am using this code from my localhost, might this be a problem?

[Code] => 1002

[Message] => Parameter has invalid value.

[Parameter] => SearchRequest.AppId

[Value] => VSwhx6yl2AOlvvTILBIhbJnWO8h0hQ5LoJkGqKp8OCY=

[HelpUrl] => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251042.aspx

I tried googling for answers, many had this same problem but I couldnt get the answers from the forums and discussion. codes I used are given below :

```
<body>
<?php
    $search = trim($_POST['search']);
    if($_POST['submit']) {
        if(strlen($search) == 0) {
            echo "<p>Error: empty search</p>";
        }
        else {
            $get = file_get_contents("http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?AppId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&Query=".urlencode($search)."&Sources=Web&Web.Count=15");
            $decode = json_decode($get, TRUE);
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($decode); // let's print it in a more readable format
            echo "</pre>";
        }
    }
?>
<div style='text-align: center'>
<h1>Search - powered by Bing</h1>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="search" size="50" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Bing" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=9C9479871FBFA822!112&app=Word&authkey=!ANNnJQREB0kDC04

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your code you are using the old API you have to use the new Bing API. See this [link](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/developer/archive/2012/05/17/bing-developer-update-2.aspx).  That API is deprecated.  You have to use azure bing API.